# Data in mySQL database cleared after re-deploying project on netbeans

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I am currently starting on a java EE project on netbeans8.0, glassfish 4.0 server and using mySQL. Everytime when I redeploy my project, the data in mySQL database was cleared, and it seems that my tables are dropped and created everytime i re-deploy or run the project. Is it got to do with my persistence unit, JDBC connection pool and resources?Any idea how I can preserve the data in my database, even after redeploying?

Answer (score 1):

Check your persistence unit?
What is your table generation strategy? 
It should be **Create** and not Drop and Create.

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved, turned out that I have to comment out the persistence unit property in the persistence.xml!